# Vim: re-run make command with previous arguments

Tags: vim

In Vim, is there a way to rerun the latest `:make` command with the same set of arguments? Something like the recompile command in Emacs.

Comment: Just type `:ma` then `<Up>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type
`:make` then press <kbd>↑</kbd> will put your last :make command in your command line. is this ok for you?

if you hate to type `:make` every time, you could bind/map your make command to some key, then you just press the key to execute your command.

P.S. anybody knows how to make "up-arrow" looks like a keyboard key with SO markdown? `<kbd>??</kbd>` `C-V <up>` doesn't work here for sure. :)

thank you Ingo Karkat!! 
<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: That's the HTML `&uarr;` entity.

Comment: To sum up, add the line `map <F4> :update<C-M>:make<Up><C-M>` to your init.vim (~/.config/nvim/init.vim for me)

Answer (score 1):

When it's still the last executed Ex command, a simple `@:` will do. If you're unsure, the suggested `:make` followed by <kbd>↑</kbd> is better. You may also like my [redocommand plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1661), which allows a recall via `:R :make` (or any shorter uniquely identifying string).

Answer (score 1):

I have the following setting, a mapping, command and a function for this:

```
command! -nargs=* Make write | let g:make_args="<args>" | make <args> | cwindow 6
function! Make2()
  if !exists("g:make_args")
    let g:make_args = ""
  endif
  wall
  exec "silent! make " . g:make_args
  cwindow 6
  redraw
endfunction
inoremap <F2> <ESC>:call Make2()<CR><C-L>
noremap <F2> :call Make2()<CR><C-L>
```

you need to explicitly call `:Make myprog` once. After that you simply type `<F2>` and and it uses the last arguments you used for your last `:Make` command. If you want to make something else just use again `:Make new_prog` explicitly.

Comment: I suggest to rename `:Make2` in `:Remake` (I think it is how it works in emacs).